# Opening a input filestream with a unicode name but ASCII data

Tags: c++, unicode, g++

I'm compiling my library with unicode support, and now I have the problem that I need to open a data file which is in ASCII, but of course the filename is with widechars. So how would I do this?

When I'm using this code:

```
std::wstring s = L"path";
std::ifstream fl;
fl.open(s.c_str(), std::fstream::in);
```

then I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(const wchar_t*, const openmode&)'
```

And when I use

```
std::wifstream fl;
fl.open(s.c_str(), std::fstream::in);
```

I get the same error (???)

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<wchar_t>::open(const wchar_t*, const openmode&)'
```

Even so, when I would use `std::wifstream`, does the stream expect the input data also be in unicode? If so, then I would have to use `std::ifstream` but I still would need to pass it the wide string, or somehow convert it to ASCII. What is the proper way to do this?

I'm using MingW gcc 4.8.3.

```
mingw32-g++.exe -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wall -g -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32 -Iinclude -c propertyfile.cpp -o propertyfile.o
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this :

```
std::wstring s = L"path";
std::string ansi( begin(s), end(s) );
std::ifstream fl ( ansi );
```

If the file is ASCII, you cannot use wifstream.

Notes that it works only if the path is pure ASCII.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is the conversion wrong, or is it just because of the wrong braces?

Comment: I do not know, this is completely legit c++11 code. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab322f7b56e94c71

Comment: @Simple, it would be nice to explain this in more detail, because I tried this, and at least it compiles. I haven't tested it yet, but I thought to try it with a small testprogram, to see if this works.

Comment: @Simple, your example is exactly the same what galop1n was posting. Except that the braces were wrong (which I corrected) but this is IMO a minor detail.

Comment: @Devolus no. Look at the output. It's completely different. You can't just convert `wchar_t`s to `char`s and expect to get reasonable output. On Windows `wchar_t`s are used to store UTF-16 code units; you can't fit an entire UTF-16 code unit into a single `char`.

Comment: Also on Windows you can't reliably open a file using an ordinary string because it interprets the `char`s based on the current code page; the characters in the path might not all be representible in the same code page.

Comment: @simple, ok I see your point. So this solution only works, as long as you use ANSI characters as wide. It would not work for real Unicode translation, right?

Comment: @Devolus ANSI is an extremely bad name to be using. Windows expects narrow strings to be in the encoding of the current code page and wide strings to be in UTF-16. You have to perform *some* translation to go from UTF-16 code points to characters in the code page, and obviously not every code point can be mapped this way. Unless you're using only ASCII characters in your `wchar_t`s this answer will not work.

Comment: There is no real way to deal with the file system with pure C++. For ANSI string stored in wstring, the truncation is valid. For a real conversion from wide to bytes, you have `std::wstring_convert::to_bytes` but i do not any idea of how ifstream would react…

Comment: @galop1n what do you mean by ANSI string? Do you mean ASCII? There is no "ANSI" encoding.

Comment: Yes, i mean ASCII, i was confused by reading ANSI in the comment.

Comment: The Microsoft version of fstreams are not even standard and have all the construtors ( char, wchar_t, string and wstring ). As i said, pure C++ cannot provide a unique solution for different OS in regards to file system.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I accepeted the answer, because this is what I'm currently using in my code now as it works with the given limitation, being aware that it is not fully compliant with Unicode support this way.

Comment: Marking this as accepted is only increasing the confusion since this only works if the string had only ASCII chars.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution for this problem.
I have two ideas for this:

1. Try to create your own file stream buf with `_wfopen`.
2. Use boost-library. [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: +1. It is unfortunate, but Windows filenames are specified in terms of UTF-16 code units (`wchar` on Windows) and Unix filenames are specified in terms of bytes (`char`, typically interpreted as UTF-8 in modern Linux/OSX). You have to switch between the bytes-oriented C standard library calls and the Windows-specific calls (like `_wfopen` or the direct Win32 API equivalents like `OpenFileW`) dependent on the platform you're running under, which is sad. (Or, as mentioned, use a library that does it for you.)

Comment: +1, this answer is much better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

`std::ifstream` is just a `std::istream` with an easy way to set a file as target. Because it doesn't allow UTF-8, you have to set the file in another way. By looking on the [istream constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/basic_istream) you should notice `std::streambuf` (which can be set/replaced by [rdbuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) too). Now you could write your own **streambuf** derived class which uses [_wfopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yeby3zcb%28v=VS.120%29.aspx), but no need: MinGW has an extension, called `__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf` (`#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>`).

From source:

```
  /**
   *  @param  __fd  An open file descriptor.
   *  @param  __mode  Same meaning as in a standard filebuf.
   *  @param  __size Optimal or preferred size of internal buffer,
   *                 in chars.
   *
   *  This constructor associates a file stream buffer with an open
   *  POSIX file descriptor. The file descriptor will be automatically
   *  closed when the stdio_filebuf is closed/destroyed.
  */
  stdio_filebuf(int __fd, std::ios_base::openmode __mode,
        size_t __size = static_cast<size_t>(BUFSIZ));

  /**
   *  @param  __f  An open @c FILE*.
   *  @param  __mode  Same meaning as in a standard filebuf.
   *  @param  __size Optimal or preferred size of internal buffer,
   *                 in chars.  Defaults to system's @c BUFSIZ.
   *
   *  This constructor associates a file stream buffer with an open
   *  C @c FILE*.  The @c FILE* will not be automatically closed when the
   *  stdio_filebuf is closed/destroyed.
  */
  stdio_filebuf(std::__c_file* __f, std::ios_base::openmode __mode,
        size_t __size = static_cast<size_t>(BUFSIZ));
```

Your only work is to translate `std::ios_base::openmode` into the mode for a file descriptor or file pointer. `FILE*` doesn't pass his ownership, so you still have to care about it, but an `std::unique_ptr` with a file closing function as deleter, bound in any way to your `stdio_filebuf`, solves this too.

MSVC supports unicode filenames by `std::wifstream` (utf-8 to utf-16 conversion by [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), Clang is compatible to MinGW.

Writing a cross-platform fstream class is easy now. First of all: derive from `std::fstream`. On Unix, your class should be like `std::fstream`, so you just have to copy the constructors (C++11 way: `using std::fstream::fstream;`). On Windows, you have to implement constructors (which just call `open`) and override [open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) member functions (at the end, everything just forwards to one open function where the work lies, nothing more).

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
fl.open(s.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
```

I'm not sure about mingw32-g++ but you should use `ios_base` on MS compiler.
As for data it expects - yes, it will expect unicode or ansi depending on type but only if you read it as text.
Read it as binary data and then just copy into your ansi array and you will get ansi text from unicode file.

Comment: The op is asking about the case when filename is UTF-8. Your solution can't open a UTF-8 encoded filename.